# Boot USB Tails through VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, boot, usb, virtualbox, tails

So I have Tails 1.2 on my USB (Disk 5) and also on a partition (2) on an external hard drive (Disk 4).  The USB shows up as 3.75GB and the partition is 6GB.  I want to be able to boot either Disk 4 or Disk 5 through virtualbox but can't seem to get around the following error Tails throws a bit after choosing to boot.

I have tried following the following tutorials:

```
 - http://www.howtogeek.com/187721/how-to-boot-from-a-usb-drive-in-virtualbox
 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvYkujvUXhc
 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWyEXGtMQjE
```

Here is the error after trying to boot the partition (with the rest of my computer):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juy4e.png]

```
microcode: CPU0 update to revision 0x29 failed
```

All three of the tutorials above still gave me the same error booting up tails as in the image.  I have tried remounting the tails iso to both the partition and usb using Universal USB Installer and Rufus.  I have also redownloaded the iso twice.  What else can I try?  Is what I'm attempting to do even possible?

EDIT: I have also gotten a new 16gb flash drive to test and gotten the exact same error still.

Comment: Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

The problem probably comes from using Universal USB Installer and Rufus.

Please try using Tails Installer instead:

1. **Machine > Settings > Storage > CD/DVD Rive > Choose a virtual CD/DVD disk file...**
2. **Open the tails-i386-*[version]*.iso** file you downloaded and boot from that.
3. **Start Tails.**
4. When you started go **Application > Tails > Tails Installer**, then use **Clone & Install** to create your Live USB

Note: the partition used by Tails will not be visible in Windows, it will display an unpartitioned drive.
Note 2: If you use Tails in a Virtual Machine the host OS sees everything.